Recombining scans of film negatives accidentally cut in half in the lab
I'm currently digitizing analog film and sometimes the lab technician did a poor job cutting the film negative in strips.
This means that sometimes I end up with a frame split across 2 film strips.
For scanning the negative film strips I use VueScan with an Epson V600 scanner and I follow the approach for Negative Lab Pro (linear RAW scans, fixed RGB exposure level for a given film roll, 2 passes for higher dynamic range, and infrared cleaning). The scans are saved as DNG.
I'm looking for ways to recombine these incorrectly cut frames. Or, more precisely, to combine the 2 DNG files and repair the cut.
Stitching in LightRoom doesn't work since there's no overlap.
Any recommendations on the approach to follow? Should I first combine both halves and do the color inversion afterwards? Which tools and steps should I follow?

I think you need an actual photo editor for this.
One workflow you could try:
Capture raw scan TIFFs with both images in Vuescan.
Import both images into a photo editor as different layers.
Make a mask for the region without film on the upper layer, probably by it's intense darkness.
Align the upper layer with the lower layer at the cut.
Retouch the area of the cut with a healing brush or clone brush or similar.
Flatten and save the image back to a high-bit tiff and process it the rest of the way in Vuescan as a raw scan.
